# How to write html entity code into an HTML file as they are?

Tags: html

I'm tring to write a code to show html entites as they are like this

©  =>  & copy;

Now here if i don't add a space b/w '&' and 'copy;' it will show as the copyright symbol which i don't want.

```html
<body>
  <p>This is <br>
 &copy; => &copy;
  </p>
  <pre>
<code>
 &copy;
</code>
  </pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can show a & sign using `&amp;`

So `&amp;copy;` would render `&copy;` as text

Answer (score 2):

Put '&' or 'copy' in a span tag.

```html
<body>
  <p>This is <br>
 &copy; => &<span>copy<span>;
  </p>
  <pre>
<code>
 &copy;
</code>
  </pre>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to use the entity for the `&` symbol. For `&copy;`, you would have to type:

```
$amp;copy;
```

This will return: &copy; (this is written as it is)

Answer (score 0):

Just use an entity for the ampersand.

```html
<p>This is <br>
 &amp;copy; => &copy;
</p>
```